# AngularJS Removing Item from Array Leaves undefined in place of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, undefined

I have been working on an AngularJS project and have come across this issue before. I have the following array in my controller like so:

`$scope.items = [];`

I then fill this array with objects from a call to our REST API:

`$http.get(API_URL_HERE).then(onSuccess);`

The onSuccess method is called and the objects fill the array. I now have:

`console.log($scope.items)` resulting in `[Object, Object, Object, ...]`

Now when I use the `$scope.items` in an AngularJS `ng-repeat` loop it works great, as it should BUT if I try to remove an element from the `$scope.items` array, it always seems to remove the element BUT replaces it with an undefined value and this undefined value is interpreted by AngularJS in the `ng-repeat` loop and outputs an empty row in the template with no data. This causes issues if using `ng-show / ng-hide` for example as even though you have no real objects in the array, it still sees it as full because it is full of `[undefined, undefined, undefined ...]`.

This is causing major headaches and I have seen other people with same issue but the fixes don't seem to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have found to this, that seems to work well is below. Please also note that some people have said this is just a pure Javascript issue, well I don't think it is, when I tried it within AngularJS and pure Javascript, I got 2 different results with the same setup and data.

For example I have a `$scope.remove` method which handles removing items from the `$scope.items` array.

When I do the following code:

`$scope.items.splice(index, 1);`

It results in this console.log output `[Object, Object, undefined, Object, ...]`.

However, by doing the following code:

`$scope.items.splice(index, 1); 
$scope.items.pop();`

Results in the following output from console.log `[Object, Object, Object]` and my `ng-repeat` loop updates as it should without the empty rows.

My solutions seems to work fine but please do let me know if you find anything wrong with it. This code certainly looks cleaner than some of the others I have spotted on different sites and is working across all browsers I have tested.

UPDATE

My `onSuccess` method looks like this:

```
var onSuccess = function(response){

    $scope.items = response.data.items;
    //results in [Object, Object, Object, ...]

};
```

My `$scope.remove` method looks like this:

```
$scope.remove = function(index){

    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    //results in [Object, Object, undefined, Object, ...]

    //add the following code
    $scope.items.pop();
    //results in [Object, Object, Object, ...] the undefined has gone

};
```

And only when adding in the pop method does it work as it should.

Comment: Could you show your code where you loop over the elements? 
And where is your splice code located? It should work without any additional statements

Comment: Alright, but where is the remove method invoked? I want to make sure that digest loop runs after that - could you please try changing $scope.items.pop(); for $scope.$apply(); for a second and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Hey, I have tried that before and I just get the AngularJS error: $digest already in progress. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Andrzef, the method is invoked on ng-click inside a div with the ng-controller set.

Comment: Than it is very strange for me. You display the list with ng-repeat, something like <tr ng-repeat="item in items"> is that right?

Comment: Yup, very strange indeed, it's just one of those little things that I can't understand why is not working. I am using <div ng-repeat="item in items">, I have scoured the AngularJS docs and can't find anything.